# Undefined in res.redirect - express, request, fs, node-uuid, path and multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to redirect the user to a signature route, passing the file name as a URL argument he is telling me that he is undefined...

Sample file as a URL argument after upload.

```
http://localhost:3000/undefined?arquivo-assinado=82a35943-5796-4d9b-b397-80d8942b6c65.pdf
```

Side-nav option click redirect to template

```
api.get("/company-parallel-and-branch", function (req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/routes/company-parallel-and-branch/';
  res.sendFile(path + "company-parallel-and-branch.html");

  require('./digital-certificate/authentication');
  require('./digital-certificate/pades-signature');
});
```

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express    = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    nunjucks   = require('nunjucks'),
    path = require('path'),
    mysql      = require('mysql'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    io = require('socket.io');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');

app.use('/upload', require('./digital-certificate/upload'));
app.use('/authentication', require('./digital-certificate/authentication'));
app.use('/pades-signature', require('./digital-certificate/pades-signature'));
app.use('/pades-signature-server-key', require('./digital-certificate/pades-signature-server-key'));
app.use('/cades-signature', require('./digital-certificate/cades-signature'));
app.use('/cades-signature-server-key', require('./digital-certificate/cades-signature-server-key'));
```

Uploader in `company-and-branch.html`

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="sendFileManager">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

`upload.js` router

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer();
var router = express.Router();
var appRoot = process.cwd();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('upload');
});

router.post('/', upload.single('sendFileManager'), function(req, res, next) {
    var fileExt = path.extname(req.file.originalname);
    var filename = uuid.v4() + fileExt;

    var appDataPath = appRoot + '/public/app-data/';
    if (!fs.existsSync(appDataPath)){
        fs.mkdirSync(appDataPath);
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(appDataPath + filename, req.file.buffer);

    res.redirect(req.query.goto + '?arquivo-assinado=' + filename);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This route `pades-signature.js` processes file uploaded

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var restPki = require('./lacuna-restpki');
var client = require('./restpki-client');

var router = express.Router();
var appRoot = process.cwd();

/*
 * GET /pades-signature
 *
 * This route initiates a PAdES signature using REST PKI and renders the signature page.
 *
 * Both PAdES signature examples, with a server file and with a file uploaded by the user, use this route. The difference
 * is that, when the file is uploaded by the user, the route is called with a URL argument named "userfile".
 */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var pdfToSignContent;

    // If the user was redirected here by the route "upload" (signature with file uploaded by user), the "userfile" URL
    // argument will contain the filename under the "public/app-data" folder. Otherwise (signature with server file), we'll
    // sign a sample document.
    if (req.query.userfile) {
        pdfToSignContent = fs.readFileSync(appRoot + '/public/app-data/' + req.query.userfile);
    } else {
        pdfToSignContent = fs.readFileSync(appRoot + '/public/SampleDocument.pdf');
    }

    // Read the contents of the PDF stamp image
    var pdfStampContent = fs.readFileSync(appRoot + '/resources/PdfStamp.png');

    // Request to be sent to REST PKI
    var restRequest = {

        // Base64-encoding of the PDF to be signed
        pdfToSign: new Buffer(pdfToSignContent).toString('base64'),

        // Signature policy (the ID below corresponds to the PAdES basic policy)
        signaturePolicyId: restPki.standardSignaturePolicies.padesBasic,

        // Set a SecurityContext to be used to determine trust in the certificate chain
        securityContextId: restPki.standardSecurityContexts.pkiBrazil,
        // Note: By changing the value above you can accept only certificates from a certain PKI, or
        // from a custom PKI configured on the REST PKI website.

        // Set the visual representation for the signature  
        visualRepresentation: {

            image: {

                // We'll use as background the image previously loaded
                resource: {
                    content: new Buffer(pdfStampContent).toString('base64'), // Base64-encoding!
                    mimeType: 'image/png'
                },

                // (optional) Opacity is an integer from 0 to 100 (0 is completely transparent, 100 is completely opaque). If omitted, 100 is assumed.
                opacity: 50,

                // (optional) Specify the image horizontal alignment. Possible values are 'Left', 'Center' and 'Right'. If omitted, 'Center' is assumed.
                horizontalAlign: 'Right',

                // (optional) Specify the image vertical alignment. Possible values are 'Top', 'Center' and 'Bottom'. If omitted, 'Center' is assumed.
                verticalAlign: 'Center'

            },

            text: {

                // The tags {{signerName}} and {{signerNationalId}} will be substituted according to the user's certificate
                // signerName -> full name of the signer
                // signerNationalId -> if the certificate is ICP-Brasil, contains the signer's CPF
                text: 'Signed by {{signerName}} ({{signerNationalId}})',

                // Specify that the signing time should also be rendered
                includeSigningTime: true,

                // Optionally set the horizontal alignment of the text ('Left' or 'Right'), if not set the default is Left
                horizontalAlign: 'Left'

            },

            position: {

                // Page on which to draw the visual representation. Negative values are counted from the end of the document (-1 is last page).
                // Zero means the signature will be placed on a new page appended to the end of the document.
                pageNumber: -1,

                // Measurement units of the values below ('Centimeters' or 'PdfPoints')
                measurementUnits: "Centimeters",

                // Automatic placing of signatures within a container, one after the other
                auto: {

                    // Specification of the container where the signatures will be placed
                    container: {
                        // Specifying left and right (but no width) results in a variable-width container with the given margins
                        left: 1.5,
                        right: 1.5,
                        // Specifying bottom and height (but no top) results in a bottom-aligned fixed-height container
                        bottom: 1.5,
                        height: 3
                    },

                    // Specification of the size of each signature rectangle
                    signatureRectangleSize: {
                        width: 7,
                        height: 3
                    },

                    // The signatures will be placed in the container side by side. If there's no room left, the signatures
                    // will "wrap" to the next row. The value below specifies the vertical distance between rows
                    rowSpacing: 1.5
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Call the action POST Api/PadesSignatures on REST PKI, which initiates the signature. 
    request.post(client.endpoint + 'Api/PadesSignatures', {

        json: true,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.accessToken },
        body: restRequest

    }, function (err, restRes, body) {

        if (restPki.checkResponse(err, restRes, body, next)) {

            // This operation yields the token, a 43-character case-sensitive URL-safe string, which identifies this signature process.
            // We'll use this value to call the signWithRestPki() method on the Web PKI component (see view 'pades-signature') and also
            // to complete the signature after the form is submitted. This should not be mistaken with the API access token.
            var token = restRes.body.token;

            // The token acquired can only be used for a single signature attempt. In order to retry the signature it is
            // necessary to get a new token. This can be a problem if the user uses the back button of the browser, since the
            // browser might show a cached page that we rendered previously, with a now stale token. To prevent this from happening,
            // we set some response headers specifying that the page should not be cached.
            res.set({
                'Cache-Control': 'private, no-store, max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache'
            });

            // Render the signature page
            res.render('pades-signature', {
                token: token,
                userfile: req.query.userfile
            });
        }

    });
});

/*
 * POST /pades-signature
 *
 * This route receives the form submission from the view 'pades-signature'. We'll call REST PKI to complete the signature.
 */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // Retrieve the token from the URL
    var token = req.body.token;

    // Call the action POST Api/PadesSignatures/{token}/Finalize on REST PKI, which finalizes the signature process and returns the signed PDF
    request.post(client.endpoint + 'Api/PadesSignatures/' + token + '/Finalize', {

        json: true,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.accessToken}

    }, function(err, restRes, body) {

        if (restPki.checkResponse(err, restRes, body, next)) {

            var signedPdfContent = new Buffer(restRes.body.signedPdf, 'base64');

            // At this point, you'd typically store the signed PDF on your database. For demonstration purposes, we'll
            // store the PDF on a temporary folder publicly accessible and render a link to it.
            var filename = uuid.v4() + '.pdf';
            var appDataPath = appRoot + '/public/app-data/';
            if (!fs.existsSync(appDataPath)){
                fs.mkdirSync(appDataPath);
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(appDataPath + filename, signedPdfContent);
            res.render('pades-signature-complete', {
                signedFileName: filename,
                signerCert: restRes.body.certificate
            });

        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thank very much for helping me ;]]

Comment: Where is the `goto` parameter sent?

Comment: @Vasan yessssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is

```
router.post('/', upload.single('sendFileManager'), function(req, res, next) {
    var fileExt = path.extname(req.file.originalname);
    var filename = uuid.v4() + fileExt;

    var appDataPath = appRoot + '/public/app-data/';
    if (!fs.existsSync(appDataPath)){
        fs.mkdirSync(appDataPath);
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(appDataPath + filename, req.file.buffer);

    res.redirect('/company-parallel-and-branch' + '?sendFileManager=' + filename);
});
```